# Alternative methods to insert Registered Trademark symbol after word because CMS not parsing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, special-characters

I am making a change to a site at the moment. One of the requests is to create a new page whose menu entry has a superscripted registered trademark sign after the word. The problem I am having is that since this is a custom written CMS, it displays the menu entity correctly but places `<sup>&reg;</sup>`in the title of the page (must be saving from the same field in CMS to populate both). Is there any way I can get rid of `<sup></sup>` in the title of the page while keeping the superscript for the menu?

Comment: There is a way, but without seeing the code/with the information you gave there's no way to help you

Comment: The problem is that this is a rather sophisticated CMS and I am new to it. I would not know where to even look for this code. Still making my way through it. What should I search for? It is build around MVC model

Comment: Do you have access to the CSS? Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: I can use anything and everything. I am just unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: Do you have the CSS styling for the menu entry?

Comment: That is the thing ... I cant seem to find it. The whole project is a big mess. It has custom code + a bunch of open source things thrown together. It is a frankenstein. There are several asset folders but I have had no luck in them. Still searching ...

Comment: It is also using a bunch of Linux symlinks in its directories that cross-reference various locations. As I said, a huge mess.

Comment: I have just done a search for all .css files in the web project's folder. Would it help if I posted the output of that command? It seems that all files are 3rd party open sources, except for a few.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title of html page using javascript. Here's one way to do using jquery:

```
$(document).prop('title', '\u00AE');
```

Please note that you need to pass unicode characters and not html entity (&reg; in this case);

You can keep the rest of the title content as well.